# putting inner python function at the bottom of the code

Tags: python, function, position

How can I put an inner python function at the bottom of the code, and call it from the beginning?
For example, VBA dosent care where the phisical inner function code is.
Rexx ( which is also interpreter) also does not care.
How can I do it in Python?
It is much easier to understand the code when the functions are at the bottom.
thanks

Comment: Depending on the scope of the modules, this is definitely possible. Could you post an example where you are experiencing problems?

Comment: This is not really possible except the code calling the inner function is itself in an inner function which is called at the end after the first function is defined. Reason is that `def` is actually a statement which must be executed (like other statements) to add a function name to the surrounding namespace. In other languages there are function definitions which are processed separately.

Comment: Functions must be defined before they are called, but that does not usually prevent anyone laying out their code in the order they want. If you're having a problem, post a [mre] and someone can suggest an approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
def main():
    print(f(3))
    
    
def f(x):
    return x * x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or do you talk about nested functions?

BTW: using the construct in the bottom of my example is anyway good practice to execute the `main` code only if the module is called as a script. And if it isn't, code shouldn't be extensively executed anyhow before the module is imported (and functions called from outside).

Answer (score 0):

You could not do that.

Python runs your code from top to bottom, so it first needs to declare your functions to access them later. You can not first access, later declare, because you would tring to access non exsistent values.

In compiled code, it may works. But in script languages, like python, it does not. As far as I know.